# Why await inside a if condition has no effect in my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I'm coding in react and I realized that my await nas no effect (at least that's what my vscode is alerting to me)

```js
const voltar = async (argumento) => {
        if(argumento == "autoriza"){
            await autoriza()
        }
        fc_volta();
        history('/')
    }

    const autoriza = () => {
        fetch('https://api.github.com/users/someuser/repos')
        .then(resposta => resposta.json())
        .then(dados => console.log(dados)) 
    }
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong?

CORRECTED BY MYSELF:
After some months training, i think it would be better if i do something like:

```js
const voltar = async (argumento) => {
        if(argumento == "autoriza"){
            fetch('https://api.github.com/users/someuser/repos')
            .then(resposta => resposta.json())
            .then(dados => console.log(dados))
        }
        fc_volta();
        history('/')
    }
```

With only one function and less code.

Comment: `autoriza` isn't `async` or doesn't return a Promise.

Comment: Depends entirely on what `authoriza()` does. If it's not async code which produces a promise, then `await()` doesn't do anything useful - true. If it is async code which produces a promise and the promise resolves when the async code finishes - then `await` is definitely useful.

Comment: To give a real answer, it will be necessary to see what "some fetch code" actually means.

Comment: you need to return the fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would rewrite it, using `await`:

```js
const voltar = async argumento => {
  if(argumento === "autoriza"){
    await autoriza();
  }
  fc_volta();
  history('/');
}

const autoriza = async () => {
  let resposta = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/someuser/repos');
  let dados = await resposta.json();
  console.log(dados);
  return dados;
}
```